# Catch error if DNS error in $.ajax call?

Tags: jquery

How do I catch error if the server that I'm calling is down (maybe because of a DNS problem)?

This doesn't do it:

```
error: function( req, status, err ) {
    console.log( 'server unreachable', status, err );
  },
```

If I use a url that I know won't resolve in the call to simulate I get no error.

**UPDATE:**

This seems to work in some quick and dirty test cases:

```
timeout: 3000,
    error: function(x, t, m) {
        if(t==="timeout") {
            alert("got timeout so probably unreachable");
        }
```

But, is that really the best way to approach?

Comment: Thats a decent way for a programmer to catch it, but not if the error becomes user facing. My advice; its good enough check for you. If a user doest it dont worry about it. Your choosen MVC framework should take care of telling the users about 503s anyway.

Comment: @agconti Thanks. I don't intend for the user to see the error as in the example. My goal here is simply to achieve the catch. I avoid alerts to users—it's just a placeholder there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will use the approach in my update.

Answer (score 1):

You could also add an option like this to your ajax call:

```
statusCode:{
    404: function(){
        alert('Page not found');
    },
    500: function(){
        alert('Page not found');
    },
    408: function(){
        alert('Request Timeout');
    }
},
```

**408 is the http status code for request timeout.*

While its functionally similar to your example, its a little neater and allows you to handle more errors in the future.